# how to pass variable value to href attribute using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use JavaScript random function for pass the different value to `href` attribute 
this is my code but it's not the jQuery part is not working:

jQuery:-

```
var numbers = ["22332233", "44455566", "12322122", "44455566", "12322122", "44455566", "12322122"];
var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
console.log(result);
console.log(numbers[result]);
$("#phone-tel").attr("href", numbers[result]);
```

HTML:-

```
<a id="phone-tel" href="">+353123456789</a>
```

Comment: what is wrong with current ?

Comment: i would start by confirming that the jquery is executed after the page is fully loaded, and html fully constructed, having your jquery in the $(function() { });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code work fine,if:-

1.jQuery library added before your script code.

2.Wrap your script code inside `$(document).ready(function(){..});`,if it is ***on top of your page***. If script code is ***on bottom of the page*** then wrapping is not necessary.

Working example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var numbers = ["22332233", "44455566", "12322122", "44455566", "12322122", "44455566", "12322122"];
  var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);  
  console.log(result);
  $("#phone-tel").attr("href",numbers[result]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="phone-tel" href="">+353123456789</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery library is missing in your code**

By adding jquery library, every thing is working fine with your code. The only issue is, there are only 7 element in the array. So most of th times random number generates the last generated number again and again. To remove this, hold the last value and generate the value other than that.